# Magento 2 - custom CSS not showing up

Tags: magento2, css

I recently started working in Magento 2, after reading docs and tutorial I set up my first magento site and is running successfully on my localhost. 
I am now setting a new Magento 2 project, I used the same way I setup the previous project, but now, my custom.css file not loading and I can't even find that in the page source if it's loaded. I've checked many times the path etc., and everything seems OK.

I've added the custom.css file in the following path:

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

I have noticed that running the command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

not generating the custom.css file in the static folder.
Please help me sort out where I am doing mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Where You added your css

Comment: Can you post the code present in default_head_blocks.xml?

Comment: also keep in mind that if you are not using grunt to compile your styles, you have to delete the contents of the `var/view_preprocessed` folder. This will hold onto a cached version of the styles, and has to be cleared, even if you are in developer mode.

Comment: @SejalShah Here is the code  

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <css src="css/custom.css" order="100" />
    </head>
</page>

Answer (score 1):

Here is 2 ways to add you custom styles in your theme.

## **1.** Backend

Navigate to Content > Design > Configuration > Select Theme > HTML Head section > Scripts and Style Sheets field

## **2.** Less processor.

here is your theme directory

> app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [yourtheme]

create new file

> Magento_Theme / web / css / source / _extend.less

add new styles here

---

### deploy changes

you need to deploy static content to see any changes. For development purpose Magento 2 provides grunt tool.

1. cp package.json.sample package.json
2. cp Gruntfile.js.sample Gruntfile.js
3. npm install (yes you need node and npm installed)
4. add your theme to this file

> dev / tools / grunt / configs / themes.js

you will find luma example here

5. cd Magento_root && grunt watch

More information here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Comment: I like your first approach. What is the script you would type into Content > Design > Configuration > Select Theme > HTML Head section > Scripts and Style Sheets field? To call your own custom CSS sheet from your theme to override everything else?

Comment: it's a raw html. There a should be the <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}styles.css" /> by default. And styles.css put in pub/media folder.

Comment: cool yeah that works.  i cant seem to get the path right....i want it to be in my theme /web/css/customcss.css

Answer (score 0):

after deploy please Confirm your custom css is created in your theme

> pub/static/frontend/Magento/[theme]/en_us

if it is not created confirm you are follow the step

Can you  please confirm did you created the below step.

> ```
> app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / Magento_Theme / layout 
> app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css
> ```

Create the following files:

> ```
> app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / Magento_Theme / layout / default_head_blocks.xml
> app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css / custom-m.css
> app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css / custom-l.css
> ```

place this code within default_head_blocks.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
>   <head>
>     <css src="css/custom-m.css" />
>     <css src="css/custom-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
>   </head>
> </page>
> ```

Comment: if you are not created like this please share xml fie.

Comment: followed the same steps as mentioned